# Logic Apps : How to get the display_value response from Http API cal

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic app, the response I am getting while I am making an Http response call is below.

```
{
 "import_set": "",
 "staging_table": "",
 "result": [
   {
    "transform_map": "",
    "table": "incident",
    "display_name": "",
    "display_value": "INC5164816461631654",
    "record_link": "",
    "status": "",
    "sys_id": ""
   }
 ]
```

}

How I can get the 'display_name' property. I tried several ways like

```
@triggers().outputs.body.result.display_name

@{body('HTTP')['result'][display_name]}
```

but it's not working.

Result: INC5164816461631654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output is in json format, you could just get it with a expression:`@body('HTTP')['result'][0]['display_name']`. Cause under tag `result` it's array, so if you don't point the index, it won't be able to find the property.

And if your output is not json format, it will be a string. you need to parse it to json. 
Then you will be able to use same expression(`@body('Parse_JSON')['result'][0]['display_name']`) to get the value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do this:

1. If you are using directly from the response try this expression as below:
   directly on expression : **triggerBody()?['result'][0]?['display_name']** or in Code view 
   like this **@triggerBody()?['result'][0]?['display_name']** the response should be a 
   proper JSON.
2. If it is not a proper json use Parse json with the payload schema and use the below 
   expression : **body('Parse_JSON')?['result'][0]?['display_name']** or in code view as 
   **@body('Parse_JSON')?['result'][0]?['display_name']**. Note replace the parse_json 
   with your corresponding shape name.
3. By declaring Variables as mentioned by George but this would increase the flow, 
   rather you can directly use the expression to extract the value.

Let me know if this helps! Cheers