# how to pass topic name as parameter based on condition in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, servicebus

In logic app I got json data from `HTTP connector` based on that i want to give topic name to `Service Bus Connector` to send message to specific `Service Bus topic`

Currently I'm directly using `Condition Connector` but instead of use `multiple condition connector` hwo can I pass topic name based on json value ?

Json data -

```
{"data":[{
"name" : "demo1",
"TableName" : "Table2"
},
{
"name" : "demo2",
"TableName" : "Table2"
}]}
```

In `for-each connector` I'm looping through `data[]` 
So based on Table name I want to pass topic name to service bus which is there inside my for-loop.
[image][![-lo]

Answer (score 1):

You can add another step in between using Condition -> and then check for the value of the table. Something like below,

[image]

Comment: but what if multiple table values need to match ? every table name is associated with topic name so if there are 100 table names i need to add 100 conditions to assign separate topic value, instead of that can i assign topic value after compare and pass that topic variable to next step ?

Comment: yes you can make use of variables assignment here and do the comparision in the assigning part

Comment: yes how can i do that can you guide me i'm bit new to logic app thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927156/logic-apps-how-to-get-the-display-value-response-from-http-api-cal/55927338#55927338